# PS3 video loop/repeat play

Tags: ps3

I have a 20 minute video on my PS3 that I'd like to play repeatedly on a loop. I have sequential playback enabled.

How exactly can I get this video to loop?

Comment: Is it stored on the Harddrive or is it a DVD /blu ray ?

Comment: On my computer's hard drive. I transferred the video to the PS3 with a USB drive.

Comment: What is the type of video file you are trying to loop?  Will it play by itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a video to loop, start the video, hit the Triangle button and choose the option on the bottom row, `Repeat` (Looks like two arrows forming an ellipse). You should see the words `Repeat On` on the bottom left corner of the screen. The video will loop until you stop it.

Answer (score 2):

In the menu system go to:

```
Video Settings > Sequential Playback on/off.
```

To have the unit repeat a video, turn Sequential playback **on.**

Then navigate to that folder where the video is stored and play it.  ( It might have to be the only item in that folder to have it loop )

*Note: This does not work for all video file types*